# Visualizing several long lists of numerical information to see relative frequency

Tags: programming, plotting, visualization

*Mathematica* has very powerful visualization techniques. However, I'm at a loss at how to best make the following chart readable.

```
BarChart3D[{viewerCount1, viewerCount2, viewerCount3}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{word1, word2}, None], 
   Placed[filelist, None]}, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Tooltip[Row[Flatten[{#3, #1}], " - "]] &)]
```

[image]

Each row (i.e. each viewerCount) is the number of times a given word appears across a large corpus of files (so if `viewerCount1` was the count for the word 'coffee,' the first row would show what files are most relevant for that word at a glance). The goal is that very quickly, an archivist could see what files are best without having to parse textual data, etc. The preprocessing of all this data has taken place in *Mathematica* so I would like to keep visualizations in there too (as opposed to learning Processing or another language).

There are 385 files being searched here, so each of those is a long list of numbers.

I have terrible handwriting, I'm afraid, but here is what I have been trying to create:

[image]

What's different in my 'dream' rather than what I have?

- Bars are more distinctive, not as flimsy
- If the value is zero, still see a little flag rectangle that can draw user to tooltip it
- spacing between the different rows, just to visually distinguish them

I suspect `BarChart3D` isn't the best command for this, but I've struggled to get other visualization techniques working. Alternatively, perhaps the problem with this visualization lies before the visualization stage itself...

**An Appendix for convenience:**

```
viewerCount1={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like an `ArrayPlot` be better? In my field, we consider 3d bar and ribbon charts to be evil.

Comment: @Verbeia This is an interesting suggestion.. I've never used `ArrayPlot`. I will check it out shortly to see what I can make of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the zeros take up a lot of space and, if I understand the problem correctly, they aren't very useful in determining which works best match a particular search.

Here is an alternative visualization that allows you to set thresholds on some basic statistics which ultimately allows you to "zoom in" on the works that are a best match under certain criteria. Note that it will drop any works where all word counts are zero (you can of course adjust this).

```
viewerCount2 = RandomChoice[viewerCount1, Length[viewerCount1]];
viewerCount3 = RandomChoice[viewerCount1, Length[viewerCount1]];

Manipulate[
 BarChart[Map[
   Tooltip[Most[#], Row[{"Work: ", Last[#], " Counts: ", Most[#]}]] &,
    DeleteCases[
    Transpose@{viewerCount1, viewerCount2, viewerCount3, 
      Range[Length[viewerCount1]]}, {x__, w_} /; 
     Max[x] <= max || Mean[{x}] <= mean]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartLegends -> {"word1", "word2", "word3"}], {max, 0, 20, 
  1}, {mean, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really promising! I'm going to plug it into my work and see how it turns out (as soon as I can get back to my office).

Comment: Accepted! I just want to again thank you for this: it's an approach that I hadn't thought, and the ability to quickly 'zoom into' the information lends itself really well to vividly showing what I want to do.

Comment: Glad it served your purposes!

Answer (score 7):

Although Andy's answer is certainly a good fit for your specific purposes, I would like to add some alternatives to illustrate why 3D charts are almost always useless for scientific research purposes. The 3D bar chart in your question is never going to be readable because there will always be issues of bars being obscured by the bars in front. The dimensions of the 3D bars do not convey information and neither does the color of the bar - only the position of the bar and its height. So much of the graphical complexity has no informational purpose.

Even aside from the data-reduction techniques such as Andy used, there are clearer and simpler ways to visualise data of this kind.

Taking your example data from your Appendix and using Andy's approach to generate two additional data sets for other "words":

```
viewerCount2 = RandomChoice[viewerCount1, Length[viewerCount1]];
viewerCount3 = RandomChoice[viewerCount1, Length[viewerCount1]];
```

And set:

```
r = Range@Length[viewerCount1];
```

Now, consider the following:

You can see the zeros at the bottom of the plot.

```
 With[{data =  MapThread[
    Tooltip[#1, #2] &, {{viewerCount1, viewerCount2, 
      viewerCount3}, {r, r, r}}, 2]}, 
 ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

This one doesn't explicitly show the zeros, but I think it looks better that way. Notice that you have to turn off `Ticks` on a `BarChart` where `Frame->True`. I am not sure why `FrameTicks` does not fully override in this case.

```
With[{data = 
   MapThread[
    Tooltip[#1, #2] &, {{viewerCount1, viewerCount2, 
      viewerCount3}, {r, r, r}}, 2]}, 
 BarChart[Transpose@data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[], ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{1, 1}, {0, 2}}, Ticks -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 400, 50], Automatic, None, None}]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[{viewerCount1, viewerCount2, viewerCount3}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

All of the above three examples show all the data, unobscured, and the first two identify the file number as a tooltip (I am not sure how that would work with `MatrixPlot`).

For more information, I recommend [any of Edward Tufte's books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_10?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=edward+tufte+books&x=0&y=0&sprefix=Edward+Tuf%2Cstripbooks%2C347) for some good guidelines on how to visualise data clearly. (I have some nice code for ["sparklines"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) if anyone is interested.)

Comment: These are very useful, Verbeia! Thanks very much. I'd love to see the sparkline code. Also, re: Tufte, do you have a favourite one of his? I've been meaning to pick one up (part of me has been hoping he would come up to Canada soon, as you get his books w/ his workshop).

Comment: One can't go wrong with Tufte's "Beautiful Evidence"

Comment: @Jagra Speak of the devil - I have just been trying to decide which Tufte book to put an order in for. Would you recommend "Beautiful Evidence" over his earlier two canonical works?

Comment: I've learned things from all of his books and recommend getting them all, but if I could only take one to a desert island, I'd take "Beautiful Evidence".  Tufte has a website with a wide range of interesting discussions: http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/